# Slice a string in javascript and manipulate it

Tags: javascript

My variable is:

```
var filePath = "C:\\Libraries\\Documents\\123_test\\Report_11071991";
```

I have a variable as above in **javascript**

Can I have some code to get only the numeric part(`11071991`) from the last folder(`Report_11071991`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Plese search **before** asking.

Comment: Did you mean javascript? `var filePath...` is not a valid variable declaration in Java (yet).

Comment: yes....I meant javascript

Comment: @jeja Then please use the javascript tag, not java...

Comment: how about a regex like `parseInt(/Report_(.*)$/.exec(filePath)[1], 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var filePath = "C:\\Libraries\\Documents\\123_test\\Report_11071999";
```

var  lastFolderName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("\")); //Report_11071999

if (lastFolderName.indexOf("Report_") >= 0) {

var out = lastFolderName.substring(7);

}

else {

out = lastFolderName;

}

Comment: This will do the job!!

Answer (score 0):

This is bad example, because no proffessional code. 
Please read articles for regular expression Pattern, Matcher.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath="C:\\Libraries\\Documents\\123_test\\Report_11071991";

    String[] lines = filePath.split("_");
    filePath=lines[lines.length-1];

    System.out.println(filePath);

 }
```

}

Comment: hmmm..split should be based on \\ and not by _ right?

Comment: I am trying with lastindexof

Comment: I am use for split symbol _

Comment: OP change to javascript. Your java code won't help him